Changing of font with ggplot2
I am working with R and I trying to make chart in ggplot2. Below you can see my data and my chart.
df <- data.frame(
  variable = c("USA", "CAN", "GBR"),
  value = c(10, 15, 20)
)

   ggplot(df, aes(x = value, y = reorder(variable, value), fill = variable)) +
                geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.5) +
                labs(title = " ", x = "  In percent ", y = "") +
                theme_minimal() +
                theme(legend.position = "none")


When I create this chart, I notice a difference between the values on the x-axis and the title. Specifically, the values appear in a gray color and are not easily readable when I insert them into Word. On the other hand, the title is in black color, which is more readable. Can anybody help me figure out how to make the values on the x-axis appear in the same black color as the title?

Add to the theme(): axis.text.x = element_text(colour="black")

Add axis.text.x = element_text(colour = 'black')) to theme(...)
